# How does Guice pass in ServletContext/ServletConfig to the bindings?

Tags: java, servlets, guice

Hi I was wondering how does Guice pass in implicit objects passed into the Servlet when we bind the route using their serve().with()?
I defined a custom Router servlet, which will create an instance of a Servlet and call its
doGet() and doPost() on request. I did this to allow Servlets under a directly lets say directory A to have automatic bindings.

We can achieve this by putting a binding to serve all the request to /A through this router and this router will in tern bind all the servlets under directory A and call doGet()/doPost() on them.
Problem with this approach is the call to getServletContext() throws NullPointerException.

For solution I ended up passing in ServletCotext from the router Servlet. (Which did not work when I attempted to redirect to a jsp)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at source, all the implicit objects are accessed through ThreadLocal.